# how to give real time input to Storm

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, apache-storm

I am trying to execute storm, Actualy data is emited from some port, using storm spout program I am listening, (ie)implementing SerialPortEventListener 
I am getting error

```
no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
5399 [Thread-26] ERROR backtype.storm.util  - Async loop died!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier
    at movingAverage.LightEventSpout.open(LightEventSpout.java:53)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997.invoke(executor.clj:460)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: can you share code snippet where you are submitting the topology to the cluster? Also info about your storm version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you failed to bundle the desired library in the jar. Make sure your `CLASSPATH` is set correctly to include the desired library so that it will be included in the jar.

Comment: @G Gordon Worley III:I have missed some jar to buid now i am getting data form external port.thanks for your reply..